# Find duplicated documents in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I would to find duplicates entries in my `CouchDB` database using `Futon`, So I would like to use the function:

```
function(doc) {
    if (condition){  
        emit([doc.type], doc);
    }
}
```

I have this `json` structure in my documents:

```
{
  "_id": "09a00ad8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "_rev": "2-e8da23aba404864xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "device_num":56,
  "plantation": {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "AGRUPATION2"
  },
  "creation_date": "26/04/2017",
  "revisionCauces": false,
  "integridad": false,
  "updated": "2017/04/26 12:22",
  "created": "user2",
  "completed": false,
  "num": 2278,
  "group": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "ZONE 4"
  }
}
```

A duplicated entry, in my case, is more than one document how has repeated the `json` fields:

> device_num

and

> num

Now If I search a document I do something like:

```
function(doc) {
    if ( doc.type == "work" && doc.num == 1667 && doc.device_num == 8 ){  
        emit([doc.type], doc);
    }
}
```

I get two results but that is something wrong because

> device_num

and

> num

should be unique. So I have to check if there are more duplicated documents on my CouchDB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I understand the question, but try this and let me know if it's usable for your case:

Map:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.device_num, doc.num], doc._id);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have just edit and add more info, is more clear or not ?¿